# unable to convert or run python 2.x code using python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm trying to solve a small python problem.i found the solution online but i'm unable to run the code in python 3.0 interpreter.i'm beginner i just started learning couple of days back please help me.

```
import string
l = string.lowercase
t = string.maketrans(l, l[2:] + l[:2]) 
m = """g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. 
     bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle.
     sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."""
print m.translate(t))
print "map".translate(t)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this code doesn't run in 2.x either. `print m.translate(t))` gives a syntax error.

Comment: You can't in general run Python 2 code on Python 3.  Did you search the web for information on differences between Python 2 and Python 3?  You should try to search for answers yourself, and then ask here with specific problems if there is something you don't understand.

Comment: @Kevin run here http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php

Comment: @BrenBarn i searched a lot i found tools like 2to3 but in documentation and when it didnot work i posted here

Comment: @BrenBarn: It is ironic that the OP used the web to cheat at the Python Challenge, but didn't managed to use the web to cheat at Stack Overflow.. :-)

Comment: @BrenBarn i'm not professional it is just 10th hour of my python learning you might criticise me but i'm  trying to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you needed, really, was the `print()` *function*, and `string.ascii_lowercase` instead of `string.lowercase`. The `string.maketrans()` function is now a class method on the `str` type:

```
import string
l = string.ascii_lowercase
t = str.maketrans(l, l[2:] + l[:2])
m = """g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. 
     bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle.
     sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."""
print(m.translate(t))
```

This is a slightly clean-up version of the code you found. Now stop cheating on the Python Challenge and solve the problems yourself. :-)

Comment: @saimadan: you'll learn faster if you don't copy code from the internet though.

Comment: can you suggest me some online resources where i can learn excluding documentation.and also to spot differences between 2.0 and 3.0

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html contains a good list at the end, as well as great advice.

Comment: i copied the code so as to find out how the code works not to submit the solution . i mentioned abovethat  i started learning just two days back

Comment: I don't think the Python Challenge is the best way to learn here, I'm afraid. Some of the puzzles require in-depth knowledge of protocols and image formats, for example.

Comment: i just googled beginner python challenge and that pythonchallenge website came in results so i just opened it and tried when i could n't do i searched for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`string.lowercase` has changed to `string.ascii_lowercase`.

`string.maketrans` is now `str.maketrans`

`print` is now a function and requires brackets.

For more information about all the changes, see [What's New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html)